# Excel file getting corrupted inside jar

Tags: java

We are using a j2ee system and the excel file when we are jarring up is getting corrupted. We are using Maven script to jar it up. Any suggestions/ideas?

Comment: How do you understand that "it is getting corrupted"?

Comment: When I am trying to open the file, its complaining that the excel is corrupt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure you disable maven filtering for any binary resources.

Answer (score 0):

It seems unlikely that the jar utility would be corrupting the file.  You might look at other possibilities.  Is the excel file being checked into source control?  Source control (particularly cvs) can corrupt files if the file is being treated as ascii instead of binary.

Comment: Good to know, but when I am opening the file which is submitted to source control, its opening fine. This is probably not happening in my case.